# Why do Star Trek Vulcans have art and music?

Tags: star-trek, music, vulcan, art

Vulcans adhere to foundations of logic. Music and art seem like emotionally driven creations.

Comment: Have you ever listened to a Bach fugue? Seen an Escher print? Some art and music are underpinned by logic rather than by emotion, even on Earth.

Comment: vulcans still take pleasure in things. they try not to let emotions drive their decisions.

Comment: There is mathematics in music

Comment: Allegedly Spock finds the playing of music to be relaxing; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan_lute

Comment: Because Vulcans aren't robots. They still appreciate beauty, art and culture, they just try not to get all emotional about it.

Comment: Art isn't emotionally driven - it's driven by the desire to create something beautiful. We humans think that's emotional because we usually try discern beauty by evaluating or emotional response to something, but as a mathematician, I can tell you there is also a very real *intellectual* aspect to beauty.

Comment: It is also obvious, even from TOS alone, that Vulcans do have emotions, even if they attempt not to be ruled by them. (see Journey to Babel an Amok Time) It seems clear that art and beauty are appreciated by Vulcans, and who ever said they were not?

Comment: Plus, out-of-universe, we don’t have a particularly firm definition of what emotions are.